# Debian11 VM cannot ping gateway, but can ping Proxmox hypervisor through linux-bridge

Tags: proxmox

I am encountering a network issue with linux-bridge in a small Proxmox cluster lab.
I have a Debian11 VM installed that can't ping the gateway, but can ping the Proxmox hypervisor.
The hypervisor uses the same bridge as the VM to be reachable.

The routes of the VM and hypervisor seem to be OK.

```
Debian IP: 192.168.3.240/24 via ens18 (card connected to vmbr0)
Hypervisor IP: 192.168.3.231/24 (indicated in vmbr0 configuration)
Gateway IP: 192.168.3.1/24
```

```
192.168.3.231 => 192.168.3.1: OK
192.168.3.240 => 192.168.3.231: OK
192.168.3.240 => 192.168.3.1: NOT OK
```

Proxmox hypervisor configuration:
/etc/network/interfaces :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet manual

auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet manual

auto enp0s9
iface enp0s9 inet manual

auto enp0s10
iface enp0s10 inet manual

auto bond2
iface bond2 inet static
        address 192.168.10.2/24
        bond-slaves enp0s10 enp0s9
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-mode balance-rr
#CEPH

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.3.231/24
        gateway 192.168.3.1
        bridge-ports enp0s3
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
```

edit routage :

```
brctl show: 
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
vmbr0           8000.08002701da38       no              enp0s3
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to add the default gateway to your VM config when adding the network adapter.
Can you show the results of

```
ip route | grep default
```

and

```
ip addr show
```

of the VM?
Also, is this IP `192.168.3.240` static or set by DHCP?